# nodejs http module server.listen(), what is the default port if we do not define the port number

Tags: node.js

```
server.listen(port, hostname, backlog, callback);
```

These parameters are all optional. So I just call

```
server.listen()
```

The server seems start and run.

but http://127.0.0.1/ or http://127.0.0.1:80, shows "This site can’t be reached"

My question is, if the port number and hostname are optional, what will be the default hostname and port number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per the docs

> If port is omitted or is 0, the operating system will assign an arbitrary unused port, which can be retrieved by using `server.address().port` after the `listening` event has been emitted.

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers from Reetesh Kumar and Venkat smart. The following code will start a server and echo out the port number.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end('Hello World!!!');
});
server.listen();
console.log(server.address().port);
```